# Why does training a neural network to replicate general univariate random distributions require multiple sources of randomness?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, random-variable

As part of building a neural network (NN) to choose continuous-valued actions in an agent-based simulation, I wanted to first see how easy it would be to train a NN that could produce values drawn from distributions specified using the 4 standardized moments: mean, variance, skewness, and kurtosis.

The inputs to my NN are IID uniform random numbers in $(0,1)$.  There is only a single fully connected hidden layer with `tanh` activation and a single linear output node.  I trained it using the cross-entropy method.  Essentially this should approximate an inverse CDF.

It turns out that it is easy to train it to replicate a distribution with a given mean and variance using only a single input and a couple hidden nodes, but to train it to also match a given skewness and kurtosis requires at least 3 inputs.  Why is this?  I was expecting to need additional hidden nodes, but it seems that at least 3 independent sources of randomness are needed:

`Input_Nodes| Error
-----------| ----------
1          | 1.377773
2          | 0.3911643
3          | 0.04052494
4          | 0.09945948
5          | 0.02489987
6          | 0.02465258
7          | 0.0424307
8          | 0.05257538
9          | 0.02362013
10         | 0.04844253`

where `Error` is just sum of the mean-squared errors for each moment when tested on a million samples.

Any tips on relevant papers would also be appreciated.

Comment: When you say you are training with cross-entropy -- you must be taking the loss with respect to some ground-truth distribution which has the specified moments? What is that family of distributions?